# Why is searching content in MS Word and PDF with SQL Server not accurate?

Tags: sql-server, pdf, ms-office

I tried to set up SQL Server to index and search MS Word and PDF files, according to  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/sqlfulltextindexing.aspx

But after I set up in SQL Server, I found some word can not be searched in SQL Server. It seems that there is problem while SQL Server indexes those files.

Anyone experienced the same thing before? What alternatives can I use to index and search the content in MS Word and PDF files?

Comment: What words, what language and what version of SQL Server?

Comment: only 70% english word can be searched use sql, both sql server 2005 and 2008

Comment: @MemoryLeak - Do you have any stop lists set up? SQL Server 2008 does have some DMVs that allow you to see much more about what is going on than 2005 does. The link to documentation on these is http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Comment: stop lists ? what do u mean by that ?  I haven't heard of this before

Comment: In SQL Server 2005 they were called noise words. Common words such as "the" that aren't worth indexing.

Comment: I tested word "thank" at the beginning of the file, but can not be searched, is it also a noise words?

Comment: Doesn't look like it is by default. On 2008 you can try this `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"a thank you"',1033,0,0)`

Comment: thanks very much, I know it is because thank start with "than", so it can not be searched, i think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF uses both text and binary data. DOC is I think entirely binary. DocX is essentially a zipped file (hence binary). Doing text search on these formats without a proper parser may not be feasible.

Comment: FTS uses `IFilters` to parse these binary formats. It comes with one that can handle `.doc` out the box and I assume the OP is aware that they need to install one for PDFs as this is in the article they link to.